# DateRangePicker on page load call a function

Tags: javascript, daterangepicker

Js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#date-range14').dateRangePicker({
        batchMode: 'week',
        showShortcuts: false,
        useCurrent: true,
        autoApply: true,
        weekStart: 0,
        autoUpdateInput: true,
        locale: {
            cancelLabel: 'Clear'
        }
    }).bind('datepicker-change', function (event, obj)
    {
        selectedStartDate = obj.date1;
        selectedEndDate = obj.date2;
        //perform action in function 
        filterBooking();
    });

}

function filterBooking() {
     console.log("call");
}
```

This code will be execute when I pick week range.
but I want default date range of current week when page is load and call the **filterBooking()** function automatically. so, which event will be triggered ??
Any Suggestion ??

Answer (score 0):

You can set the date's using daterangepicker initialization. But if you want to call a function on page load you can do this since daterangepicker does not have any special event to do that

```
$('#date-range14').load(function () {
  filterBooking();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I you want to call `filterBooking()` on page load, you could try using `.load()` method like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#date-range14").load(function() {
        filterBooking();
    });
});
```